# D3js custom control issue in Openui5

Tags: sapui5

I am using openui5 Tabstrip. Each Tab contains seperate js and controller.
again each tab contains two views(i am using sap.m.NavContainer) and each view is a seperate js view.
and i write custom control for d3 js bullet chart as followes
var thisId;

/* Bullet chart: A UI5 custom control wrapping some D3.js code */

```
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("control.BulletChart", { 
    /* the control API */
    metadata : {
         properties : {
                "items" : { type: "any" },
                "colorType" :{type:"string"},
                "height" : {type: "int"},
                "width" : {type: "int"},
                "popup" : {type: "any"}
            },
        events: {
            "select" : {},
            "selectEnd": {},
            //"click": {}
        }           
    },


    // the part creating the HTML:
    renderer : function(oRm, oControl) {    
        oRm.write("<div"); 
        oRm.writeControlData(oControl); 
        oRm.addClass("bullet");             
        oRm.writeClasses();                             
        oRm.write(">");
        oRm.write("</div>");
    },

    onAfterRendering: function() {
        var that = this;

        var deepClonedCopy = jQuery.extend(true, {}, this.getItems());
        var data;
        data = $.map(deepClonedCopy, function(el) { return el });
        var customId=this.getId();

        if(data){
        if(data[0]){
        data[0].ranges = JSON.parse("["+data[0].RANGES+"]");
        data[0].measures = JSON.parse("["+data[0].MEASURES+"]");
        data[0].markers = JSON.parse("["+data[0].MARKERS+"]");
        }

        var containerWidth = $("#"+customId).parent().width(); 
        var margin = {top: 15, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 30},
        width = containerWidth- margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 65 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        console.log("Actual bulletWidth",width);
        var chart = d3.bullet()
        .width(width)
        .height(height);
        var classType;
        if(this.getColorType()){
            classType = "reversebullet";
        }
        else{
            classType = "bullet";
        }
        var svg = d3.select("#"+customId).selectAll("svg")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg")
          .attr("class", classType)
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          //.on("click", click)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
          .call(chart);
         }

});
```

Now my problem is I am using something like this in my `view.js`

```
bulletChart = new control.BulletChart({
                                              layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "L8 M12 S12"}),
                                            items: {
                                                path : "/genericData",
                                                }   
                                        }),
```

And in my controller the below code is written in onInit:

```
var oBusinessData = {
                                    "genericData":[
                                        { "key":"1","RANGES":"50,75,100","MEASURES":20,"MARKERS":80,"tab":"sdto"},
                                ]};
buBullet.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oBusinessData ));
```

As per above code when I open tab for the 1st time it works perfectly but when I switch tab and my bullet chart appears squeezed. When I put alert to `var containerWidth = $("#"+customId).parent().width();` I see a less width than it actually is may be due to chart rendering happens more quickly than its parent so putting setTimeout solves the issue time being but is not a proper fix. Can anyone tell how to avoid it and render the chart after the view is rendered. So the above problem is when using navcontainer with two views inside a single tab.
and if i change from one tab to another tab and then come back same tab the active view is working fine but if i navigate second view the problem occurred.
this problem happens only when i change tab view.

Answer (score 0):

you should register an onAfterRendering Event to the control instead of using "setTimout", by doing this you can get the correct timing when the rendering has been finished.

```
parentControl.addEventDelegate({  
                  "onAfterRendering": function() {  
                      // parentControl has been rendered, here comes the code..
                      // Now here has the rendering finished, now you can get 
                      // the correct height of parentControl.
                  }  
            }, this);
```

Edited the Comment, hope it will help you ;)

Comment: how is it different from the onAfterRendering in the above code.

Comment: The difference is that the onAfterRendering Method you implemented is called when your customcontrol is rendered. But you want the height of the parent control, so you got to set an individual onAfterRendering-Event to the parent Control.

Comment: I wrote something like [this](https://titanpad.com/GqVn4ANKXQ) but I am getting `Error: failed to load 'chartControls/customBullet.js' from ./chartControls/customBullet.js: SyntaxError: missing : after property id`.

Comment: I tried it is giving the same result as without timeout.